# UIView w/animation not removed after removeFromSuperview()

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkIGW.jpg

I have a custom UIView with an animation when my app first opens.

```
fileprivate func startAnimation() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: self.scaleTime, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.one.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: self.scaleFactor, y: self.scaleFactor)
    }) { (complete) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: self.scaleTime, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.one.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
            self.two.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: self.scaleFactor, y: self.scaleFactor)
        }) { (complete) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: self.scaleTime, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.two.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
                self.three.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: self.scaleFactor, y: self.scaleFactor)
            }) { (complete) in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: self.scaleTime, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                    self.three.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
                    self.four.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: self.scaleFactor, y: self.scaleFactor)
                }) { (complete) in
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: self.scaleTime, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                        self.four.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
                        self.five.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: self.scaleFactor, y: self.scaleFactor)
                    }) { (complete) in
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: self.scaleTime, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                            self.five.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
                        }) { (complete) in
                            self.startAnimation()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This loops and achieves the effect I wanted.  However when I remove my animating view from its superview, the animation continues and it does not get removed.

Comment: Have you tried removing the animations view.layer.removeAllAnimations()?

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting an iOS version 10 or higher I'd advise to look into UIViewPropertyAnimator for cancellable animations. Animations can be reversed as well, which can be nice for your loader.